# Implement filtering in ViewModel class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I've known of `CollectionView` which supports filtering well. However I have a separate ViewModel project (containing view model classes), to use `CollectionView` I need to reference `PresentationFramework.dll` in that project. I wonder if that is a good design?

Without using `CollectionView` I need to do the filtering myself, which is more likely troublesome but more data-oriented, while `CollectionView` involves a little UI although we can get the default `CollectionView` just via `CollectionViewSource`. Referencing `PresentationFramework.dll` just to use `CollectionView` is also my concern.

I wonder if any one here did something like that and is that a good practice? I'm sure everything will just work but what I care about is some good practice to follow.

Comment: We've seem some discussion here on SO about whether it's good practice to use WPF types in a view model. I'd say no problem, it is a view model for a WPF application, so there is nothing that stops me from using framework types. It is a matter of taste. If you would use types like `Color`, `Brush`, `BitmapSource`, you may as well use `CollectionView`.

Comment: `"Without using CollectionView I need to do the filtering myself, which is more likely troublesome but more data-oriented"` It also means it can be unit-tested, a not-entirely-insignificant factor to take into consideration!

Comment: with using ICollectionView the viewmodel is still testable - so its ok :)

Comment: thank you all for your comments, it's really helpful :)